# Assignment: Python 3.3: add keys and values from dictionary to class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, python-3.3

How can you take key/value pairs from a dictionary, and use as attributes in instances in a class? I'm sure it should go through a for loop, but I'm not exactly sure what syntax to use. Here is my code:

```
from random import randint
import time
drivers={}

class car:
    def __init__(self, Driver, Sponsor, Odometer=0,Speed=randint(1,121)):
        self.Driver = Driver
        self.Sponsor = Sponsor
        self.Odometer = Odometer
        self.Speed = Speed
    def update():
        Odometer=Odometer+Speed*0.17
        Speed = randint(1,121)
drivers['David']='Burger King'
drivers['Travis']='Dr Pepper'
drivers['Landon']='Precon Marine'
drivers['Jamie']='Cessna'
drivers['Juan']='Target'
drivers['Ken']='Federated Auto Parts'
drivers['Timmy']='OXYwater'
drivers['Josh']='MDS Transport'
drivers['Kurt']='Furniture Row'
drivers['Casey']='Geico'
drivers['Kasey']='Farmers Insurance'
drivers['Jeff']='Axalta'
drivers['Jimmie']='Lowes'
drivers['Dale']='National Guard'
drivers['Mike']='Plinker Tactical'
drivers['Denny']='FedEx'
drivers['Kyle']='Mars Brands'
drivers['Matt']='Husky'
drivers['Bobby']='Kingsford'
drivers['Clint']='5-Hour Energy'
```

I realize that the drivers dictionary is long (and there might be an easier method to add all these drivers). I needed to add in 20 drivers and their sponsors in a list (or dictionary, in this case). Would it be easier to simply add them into the class, rather than using a for loop? And is there a way to add in the driver name and sponsor as attributes, while using the default values for the Odometer and Speed?

Comment: As a side note, you really should be consistent with your capitalization. Ideally follow [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style: `Car`, `drivers`, `self.driver`, etc. But even if you choose to use a different style, use whatever you choose consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I realize that the drivers dictionary is long (and there might be an easier method to add all these drivers).

Yes, you can use a dict display:

```
drivers = {
    'David': 'Burger King',
    'Travis': 'Dr Pepper',
    # ...
}
```

> is there a way to add in the driver name and sponsor as attributes, while using the default values for the Odometer and Speed?

Yes. In fact, you've already done it. The way you've defined `car.__init__`, you just leave out the other two params, and they'll get the default values:

```
>>> david = car('David', 'Burger King')
>>> david.Driver
'David'
>>> david.Odometer
0
```

So, now all you're missing is a way to create the 20 `car` instances out of your `drivers` dict.

Assuming you want a `dict` that maps driver names to `car` instances, use a dict comprehension:

```
cars = {driver: car(driver, sponsor) for driver, sponsor in drivers.items()}
```

Or, if you just want a `list` of `car` instances, use a list comprehension instead:

```
cars = [car(driver, sponsor) for driver, sponsor in drivers.items()]
```

---

Another thing: The way you've defined `car.__init__`, you're using a single random number for every car's speed:

```
def __init__(self, Driver, Sponsor, Odometer=0,Speed=randint(1,121)):
```

When Python evaluates this function definition, it will call `randint(1,121)` and make the result the default value for every call to the function.

What you want is probably something like this:

```
def __init__(self, Driver, Sponsor, Odometer=0, Speed=None):
    if speed is None:
        speed = randint(1,121)
```

---

Finally, your `update` method needs to take a `self` parameter, and it needs to use that to access or modify the object's attributes, just like your `__init__` method:

```
def update(self):
    self.Odometer = self.Odometer + self.Speed*0.17
    self.Speed = randint(1,121)
```

---

From the comments, it sounds like the only thing you need to do with this is repeatedly loop over all cars, and then search for the winner at the end. For that, you don't have a need for a dict of cars, just a list. So:

```
cars = [car(driver, sponsor) for driver, sponsor in drivers.items()]
```

Now, here's what you do every minute:

```
for car in cars:
    car.update()
```

And then, at the end, the winner is:

```
winner = max(cars, key=operator.attrgetter('Odometer'))
```

The `max` function, like most sorting and searching functions in Python, takes an optional `key`, which is a function that tells it what to sort or search by. And `attrgetter(name)` is a function call that returns a function that gets the attribute named `name` for any object. See the [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) for details.

For comparison, let's write that part explicitly:

```
winner = None
for car in cars:
    if winner is None or car.Odometer > winner.Odometer:
        winner = car
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, using a dict comprehension will map the drivers list to the Driver and Sponsor attributes in the car class, and will use the Driver name as the self, is that correct? So I should be able to call a car object like David.car or check the Odometer with David.Odometer? As far as manipulating the data, what is the advantage of a dict comprehension over a list comprehension? Thanks for taking time and effort to help educate. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JustinDay: Using a dict comprehension will map each driver (a string like `"David"`) to a `car` object (which has `Driver` and `Sponsor` attributes, as well as `Odomoter` and `Speed` attributes). You don't get a `car` instance named `David`, but you _do_ get a car instance named `cars["David"]`.

Comment: @JustinDay: And the advantage of using a dict over a list is that you have this mapping. Otherwise, you just get a car instance named `cars[0]`. If you don't ever need to know which car is David's, which car is Travis's, etc., and all you need is a list of all your cars that you can loop over, then a list is better. If you ever need to know which car is David's, a dict is better.

Comment: Finally: Of course you _can_ always write `David = cars["David"]`. But you probably don't want to do that. Normally, when you have 20-odd objects, you don't want 20-odd variables, you want a single collection (dict or list, as appropriate) with 20-odd members. Of course the details depend on what your code is _doing_ with those objects, so without seeing more code (or pseudocode) it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Aha! That makes perfect sense. The dict comprehension will be the tool to use in this case, because I am going to need to update the Odometer and Speed of each car, every minute, and then I will need to check for Odometer>500, which will determine the winner of the race. So I will need to be able to print out the car object that wins the race, if that makes sense. I know I'm looking at a for loop (I hate those).

Comment: @JustinDay: If you just need to deal with "each car", without referring to them by driver name, a list is actually better. Let me edit my answer to give you some sample code.

Comment: Is there a better place to discuss this? I know that we are not supposed to have long discussions in comments, but my rep is only 12, so I can't chat...

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
cars = [car(driver, sponsor) for driver, sponsor in drivers.items()]
```

This is called a list comprehension, and it creates a list of car objects, each using a driver and corresponding sponsor from the dictionary (but the default values of Odometer and Speed).

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems here:

- `Speed` refers to a local variable. In `car.update`, `Speed` isn't defined. `self.Speed` is what you're looking for.
- `def __init__(self, ..., Speed=randint(1,121)):` will give all of the drivers the same random starting speed.
- `car.update` needs to be passed a `self` argument.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import random
import time

drivers = {
    'David': 'Burger King',
    'Travis': 'Dr Pepper',
    'Landon': 'Precon Marine',
    'Jamie': 'Cessna',
    'Juan': 'Target',
    'Ken': 'Federated Auto Parts',
    'Timmy': 'OXYwater',
    'Josh': 'MDS Transport',
    'Kurt': 'Furniture Row',
    'Casey': 'Geico',
    'Kasey': 'Farmers Insurance',
    'Jeff': 'Axalta',
    'Jimmie': 'Lowes',
    'Dale': 'National Guard',
    'Mike': 'Plinker Tactical',
    'Denny': 'FedEx',
    'Kyle': 'Mars Brands',
    'Matt': 'Husky',
    'Bobby': 'Kingsford',
    'Clint': '5-Hour Energy'
}

class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, sponsor, odometer=0, speed=None):
        self.driver = driver
        self.sponsor = sponsor
        self.odometer = odometer

        if speed is None:
            self.speed = random.randint(1, 121)
        else:
            self.speed = speed

    def update(self):
        self.odometer += self.speed * 0.17
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 121)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cars = []

    for driver, sponsor in drivers.items():
        car = Car(driver, sponsor)
        cars.append(car)
```

You could write this part:

```
    if speed is None:
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 121)
    else:
        self.speed = speed
```

More concisely as:

```
    self.speed = speed or random.randint(1, 121)
```